Not getting the full Timing Report in Synthesis Report
I wrote a code for Register Bank and synthesized on ISE software but I am not getting the Full Timing Report , specifically delay of the design (Section under Synthesis Report). Maybe it is because of too many warnings I am getting.
Here is the code:
module Buffer
# (parameter COUNT= 253)//   Size of Line Buffer 
  (
    input clk,rst,
    input [7:0]Pixel,
    output reg [7:0] R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,R9
    );
    
    reg [7:0] line_buff1 [COUNT-1:0];
    reg [7:0] line_buff2 [COUNT-1:0];
    reg [7:0] RT1,RT2,RT3,RT4,RT5,RT6,RT7,RT8,RT9;// Temporary  Registers
    integer i;
    
    always @ (posedge clk)
    begin
    if(rst) begin
    RT7 <= 1'd0;
    RT8 <= 1'd0;
    RT9 <= 1'd0;
    RT4 <= 1'd0;
    RT5 <= 1'd0;
    RT6 <= 1'd0;
    RT1 <= 1'd0;
    RT2 <= 1'd0;
    RT3 <= 1'd0;
    end
    
    else begin
    
    RT9 <= Pixel;
    RT8 <= RT9;
    RT7 <= RT8;
    line_buff2[0] <= RT7;
    RT6 <= line_buff2[COUNT-1];
    
    for ( i=COUNT-2 ; i>=0; i=i-1 )
        line_buff2[i+1] <= line_buff2[i];
 
 
     RT5 <= RT6;
     RT4 <= RT5;
     line_buff1[0] <= RT4;
     RT3 <= line_buff1[COUNT-1];
     
     for ( i=COUNT-2 ; i>=0; i=i-1 )
         line_buff1[i+1] <= line_buff1[i];
   RT2 <= RT3;
   RT1 <= RT2;
   end
   end
   
   
   
   always @(*)
   if(RT1 !== 8'bx)  begin
   R1<=RT1;
   R2<=RT2;
   R3<=RT3;
   R4<=RT4;
   R5<=RT5;
   R6<=RT6;
   R7<=RT7;
   R8<=RT8;
   R9<=RT9;
   end 
   
  endmodule

There are a lot of warnings, so I won't be able to show it here but if you try it on ISE you could see it for yourself.
I am expecting to get DELAY of the design in the synthesis report.

The first problem is this line if(RT1 !== 8'bx)  begin
Synthesis does not know how to check for don't cares in this context.  You can check for constant literals, however not 'x' in synthesis.  There are some exceptions like optimizations that can be made when designing state machines; this in not one of those exceptions.
I don't think synthesis is finishing and producing a design with any logic inferred.
I don't see what you are trying to accomplish by checking for x.  Just get rid of the if. Also change the non-blocking assignments to blocking for combinational logic.  Its fine to have x's at the output of a module near the beginning of a simulation until the pipeline is initialized or filled with incoming data.
 always @(*) begin
   R1 = RT1;
   R2 = RT2;
   R3 = RT3;
   R4 = RT4;
   R5 = RT5;
   R6 = RT6;
   R7 = RT7;
   R8 = RT8;
   R9 = RT9;
 end 

Re-run synthesis and see if you get better results.
You will need a timing constraint to get a timing report that makes sense.  The timing analyzer provides analysis based on constraints.
